# RandomPoint crashes kernel

Tags: bugs, random, regions, crash, version-11

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and fixed in 11.1**

---

Reported as CASE:3686963, 12 Aug 2016

I attempted to determine whether the problem with `RandomPoint` identified in [my answer to question 89384](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89538/1063) had been fixed in

```
$Version
(* 11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016) *)
```

In fact, a worse problem seems to have arisen.  I began by attempting to reproduce the first plot in the question by

```
s = 0.36109;
t = 1*(1 - s);
equation1 = 1.505 < (1 - s)*8*(Sin[2*x]*Sin[z]*Cos[y] + Sin[2*y]*Sin[x]*Cos[z] +
    Sin[2*z]*Sin[y]*Cos[x]) - s*4*(Cos[2*x]*Cos[2*y] + Cos[2*y]*Cos[2*z] + 
    Cos[2*z]*Cos[2*x]) - t;
region1 = ImplicitRegion[equation1 && 6 <= x - y + 2*z <= 7, {{x, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, 
    {y, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {z, -10, 10}}];
RandomPoint[region1, 10^4];
```

However, `RandomPoint` ran for about 30 minutes, consuming as much as 12 GB of memory, before the kernel crashed.  This behavior is reproducible on my computer.

In contrast,

```
$Version
(* 10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016) *)
```

produces the result in the earlier question in a few seconds, as did version 10.2.0.

My questions are,

- Can others reproduce this behavior?
- Is it a bug?

**Addendum**

As [István Zachar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/89/istv%C3%A1n-zachar) points out in a comment below, `region1` can be displayed with `RegionPlot3D`, which takes a few minutes.

```
RegionPlot3D[region1, PlotPoints -> 200, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Although `region1` is complicated, it does occupy a reasonable fraction of the plane on which it lies.  Further, the plane itself can be represented in a few seconds by `RandomPoint`

```
region2 = ImplicitRegion[6 < x - y + 2*z < 7, 
    {{x, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {y, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {z, -10, 10}}];
pts2 = RandomPoint[region2, 10^4];
plt2 = ListPointPlot3D[pts2, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{x, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {y, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {z, -10, 10}}]
```

[image]

Yet, `RandomPoint` cannot find even a single point in `region1`.

```
pts1 = RandomPoint[region1]
```

Instead, it also fails in about 30 minutes after using over 12 GB of memory.

Comment: I can reproduce the behaviour in 11.0 while in 10.4 it's perfectly fine. I suspect this is a bug.

Comment: I'm seeing this too, perhaps report it. It seems quite severe...

Comment: Are you sure that your region is not one with lots of disconnected almost-nulldimensional subregions on which RandomPoint ultimately runs out of memory and crashes? Because `RegionMeasure[region1]` fails on it too, and `RegionPlot3D[region1, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 1]` shows something like this. It would be easier to debug the issue if you were to simplify your region to 2D, as the 3D plot indicates that the region is actually along a plane.

Comment: @IstvánZachar  Thank you for your observations, which prompted my addition to the question above.

Comment: It is `RegionDimension[region1]` that is having trouble, in 10.4 it would give up quickly.

Comment: @ilian  Please elaborate, perhaps in the form of an answer..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As part of its algorithm, [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html) attempts to determine the region dimension by calling

```
RegionDimension[region1]
```

In version 10.4, the above gives up quickly without returning a result, and [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html) proceeds by using a heuristic estimate. But in version 11.0, [`RegionDimension`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDimension.html) tries harder to compute the dimension, which is a rather costly symbolic computation going through heavy machinery like [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html). It may be very slow and there is no guarantee of success, particularly in the case of a transcendental system.

Thank you for bringing up this example, the developers are aware of the issue and will look into possible improvements (for example, [`TimeConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeConstrained.html) could have been used to keep the runaway computation at bay).

Comment: Do you think [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124213/12) is a bug?  If yes, can you tag accordingly please?

Comment: Could you take a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118931/12) (different) post and see if any of those behaviours may be bugs?  It's all too vague to write to support but it looks like it's worth pointing it out.