# Bug: Calling `SetSharedVariable` while kernels are running hangs them up/crashes them

Tags: bugs, parallelization, kernel

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

Start a fresh kernel `Quit`, and maybe launch `` Parallel`Developer`KernelStatus[] ``, that is <kbd>Evaluation > Parallel Kernel Status...</kbd>.

The following succeeds and finishes:

```
dummy = ParallelSubmit[Null];
w = ParallelSubmit[Pause[2]]
WaitAll[dummy]
WaitAll[w]
```

This however never stops

```
dummy = ParallelSubmit[Null];
w = ParallelSubmit[Pause[2]]
WaitAll[dummy]
SetSharedVariable[x];
WaitAll[w]
```

and generates

> `` Parallel`Developer`QueueRun::hmm ``: Received unexpected result `Null` from `KernelObject[3,local]`.

Calling `` Parallel`Developer`QueueRun[] `` directly instead of relying on a dummy task and `WaitAll` to do it, reveals that the kernels get locked up one after the other:

```
ParallelSubmit[Pause[2]]
Parallel`Developer`QueueRun[]
SetSharedVariable[u];
Parallel`Developer`QueueRun[]
```

Will on the first run create an `EvaluationObject` saying that it is running on kernel 4, then on the next run on kernel 3, etc., until the the task just stays `ready for processing`.

I am positive that the problem comes from `SetSharedVariable`, probably because it is trying to communicate with the running kernels and failing. Still I think this shouldn't crash/hang up the kernels.

Worth reporting?

Comment: Yes, worth reporting.

Comment: I filed a report.

Comment: The reply is "I was able to reproduce the issue and have filed a report to the development team, raising this issue to them."